# Physical significance of electrode potential for M^2+/M where M is a 3d series d-block metal

Tags: electrochemistry, transition-metals

What is the actual meaning of electrode potential of $\ce{Cu^2+}$/$\ce{Cu}$ having a positive value? Does that mean that the reaction  (i.e. $\ce{Cu^2+ + 2e-  ->  Cu}$) will want to happen more vigorously than the elements having a negative value or is it the other way round?

From my understanding, since the configuration of $\ce{Cu^2+}$ is $[\ce{Ar}]\mathrm{3d^{9}}$ and the configuration of $\ce{Cu}$ is $[\ce{Ar}]\mathrm{3d^{10}4s^{1}}$, the reaction will happen more vigorously than others with a negative value becuase the end product has a fully filled d-subshell and should be more stable.

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: You may find useful reviewing of search results for 
[site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org OR site:hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu significance electrode potential](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alibretexts.org+OR+site%3Astackexchange.com+OR+site%3Awikipedia.org+OR+site%3Ahyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu+significance+electrode+potential)